# Simplifying a Boolean expression with four variables

Tags: boolean-algebra

Below is a problem I attempted from one of the popular books on Computer Architecture. After nearly two pages of work, I am not close to the answer. I am thinking there should be a much easier way.

Note: I am not currently taking any courses and I am not planning on taking any courses. That is, I am not currently a student and I am not planning on becoming one.

Problem:

Prove the following Boolean equation using algebraic manipulations:
$$ WY + \bar{W}Y\bar{Z} + WXZ + \bar{W}X\bar{Y}
        = WY + \bar{W}X\bar{Z} + \bar{X} Y \bar{Z} + X\bar{Y}Z $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
\bar{W}Y\bar{Z} + WXZ + \bar{W}X\bar{Y} &=
\overline {
    \overline  { \bar{W}Y\bar{Z} + WXZ + \bar{W}X\bar{Y} }
} \\
%
\bar{W}Y\bar{Z} + WXZ + \bar{W}X\bar{Y} &=
\overline {
    (W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z})(W + \bar{X} + Y)
} \\
%
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) &=
    W (\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) +
    \bar{Y}(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) +
    Z (\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) \\
%
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) &=
    W \bar{W} + W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
    \bar{Y}(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) +
    Z (\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) \\
%
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) &=
    W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
    \bar{Y}\bar{W} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Z}\bar{Y} +
    \bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z + \bar{Z}Z \\
%
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z}) &=
    W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
    \bar{W} \bar{Y} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} +
    \bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z})(W + \bar{X} + Y) &= \\
W
(   W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
\bar{W} \bar{Y} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} +
\bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) \\
+
\bar{X} (   W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
\bar{W} \bar{Y} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} +
\bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) \\
+ Y(    W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
\bar{W} \bar{Y} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} +
\bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) \\
\\
%
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z})(W + \bar{X} + Y) = \\
W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} + W \bar{Y} \bar{Z} + W \bar{X}Z \\
+
\bar{X} (   W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
\bar{W} \bar{Y} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} +
\bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) \\
+ Y(    W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
\bar{W} \bar{Y} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} +
\bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) \\
%
\\
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z})(W + \bar{X} + Y) = \\
W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} + W \bar{Y} \bar{Z} \\
+
\bar{X} (   W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
\bar{W} \bar{Y} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} +
\bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) \\
+ Y(    W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} +
\bar{W} \bar{Y} + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} +
\bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) \\
%
\bar{X} (   W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} + \bar{W} \bar{Y}
    + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} + \bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) &= \\
W \bar{X} + W \bar{X} \bar{Z} + \bar{W} \bar{X} \bar{Y}
+ \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{X} \bar{Y} \bar{Z} + \bar{W} \bar{X} Z + \bar{X}Z \\
%
\\
\bar{X} (   W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} + \bar{W} \bar{Y}
+ \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} \bar{Z} + \bar{W}Z + \bar{X}Z  ) &= \\
W \bar{X} + \bar{W} \bar{X} \bar{Y}
+ \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{W} \bar{X} Z + \bar{X}Z \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z})(W + \bar{X} + Y) = \\
    W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} + W \bar{Y} \bar{Z} \\
    +
    W \bar{X} + \bar{W} \bar{X} \bar{Y}
    + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{W} \bar{X} Z + \bar{X}Z \\
    + W \bar{X} Y + W \bar{Z} Y +
    \bar{W}Y Z + \bar{X} Y Z \\
%
\\
(W + \bar{Y} + Z)(\bar{W} + \bar{X} + \bar{Z})(W + \bar{X} + Y) = \\
    W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} + W \bar{Y} \bar{Z} \\
    +
    W \bar{X} + 
    + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{W} \bar{X} Z + \bar{X}Z \\
    + W Y \bar{Z} +
    \bar{W}Y Z \\
%
\bar{W}Y\bar{Z} + WXZ + \bar{W}X\bar{Y} &= \\
\overline {
        W \bar{X} + W \bar{Z} + W \bar{Y} \bar{Z} 
    +
    W \bar{X}
    + \bar{X}\bar{Y} + \bar{W} \bar{X} Z + \bar{X}Z 
    + W Y \bar{Z} +     \bar{W}Y Z 
} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: You have gone down a rabbit hole.  Why did you remove WY?  Throw your work out.  Expand WY with X & Z and expand the three terms, then rearrange to get desired output.

Comment: To what @StainlessSteelRat said - remember, this is not your "regular" arithmetic. There is no "-" operation, so you can't apply to both sides. To convince yourself, consider the following true equation: `1 + 1 = 1 + 0` . Now, if you "remove" `1` from both sides you will end u with `1 = 0` which is obviously false.

Comment: Be aware that when you solve these problems you may reach a dead end where everything you did is valid, but you took a pathway that doesn't allow you to solve the problem any easier.  You have to back-up some steps and try some different series of simplifications in order to prove whatever you set out to prove.  As long as every step is valid, you can still simplify, as that is the nature of boolean logic, but you can inadvertently dig yourself deeper in a hole.  Practice makes perfect.  Keep on with the self-study!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob, just keep in mind that all terms (I use that term, advisedly, as you should keep in mind what a mathematician *means* when they say 'term' or 'factor') can be expanded to all variables by populating them with all possible permutations of the unstated variables. So when I write \$X\;Y\;Z\$ in the context of four variables, \$W\$, \$X\$, \$Y\$, and \$Z\$, you ***must*** recognize that this is the same thing as \$\overline{W}\;X\;Y\;Z+W\;X\;Y\;Z\$ as you can apply the distributive property to see that \$\overline{W}\;X\;Y\;Z+W\;X\;Y\;Z=\left(\overline{W}+W\right)X\;Y\;Z\$ and that is the same as \$\left(True\right)X\;Y\;Z=X\;Y\;Z\$.

In your case, just examine each term of the left-hand expression, in turn, and verify that all of its meaning can also be found in a term of the right-hand expression. Similarly, examine each term of the right-hand expression, in turn, and verify that all of its meaning can also be found in a term of the left-hand expression. If both sides cross-correlate, then you are done and you know they are equivalent.

Your equation is:

$$\begin{align*}
W Y + \overline{W} Y \overline{Z} + W X Z + \overline{W} X \overline{Y} &= W Y + \overline{W} X \overline{Z} + \overline{X} Y \overline{Z} +  X \overline{Y} Z
\end{align*}$$

Working the left-side expression, first, I'll take each left-side term one at a time. I'll highlight each step by underlining the terms I'm examining and raising them up a bit. That way you'll know how it is that I'm saying "this side" is matched by "that side":

$$\begin{smallmatrix}
\underline{^{W Y}} &=& \underline{^{W Y}} &+& \overline{W} X \overline{Z} &+& \overline{X} Y \overline{Z} &+&  X \overline{Y} Z
\\\\
\underline{^{\overline{W} XY \overline{Z}+\overline{W} \overline{X} Y \overline{Z}}} &=& W Y &+& \left[\underline{^{\overline{W} X Y\overline{Z}}}+\overline{W} X \overline{Y}\overline{Z}\right] &+& \left[W\overline{X} Y \overline{Z}+\underline{^{\overline{W}\overline{X} Y \overline{Z}}}\right] &+&  X \overline{Y} Z
\\\\
\underline{^{W X Y Z+W X \overline{Y}Z}} &=& \left[\underline{^{W X Y Z}}+{W X Y \overline{Z}}+W\overline{X}Y\right] &+& \overline{W} X \overline{Z} &+& \overline{X} Y \overline{Z} &+&  \left[\underline{^{W X \overline{Y} Z}}+\overline{W} X \overline{Y} Z\right]
\\\\
\underline{^{\overline{W} X \overline{Y}Z+\overline{W} X \overline{Y}\overline{Z}}}&=& W Y &+& \left[{\overline{W} X Y\overline{Z}}+\underline{^{\overline{W} X \overline{Y}\overline{Z}}}\right] &+& \overline{X} Y \overline{Z} &+&  \left[{W X \overline{Y} Z}+\underline{^{\overline{W} X \overline{Y} Z}}\right]
\end{smallmatrix}$$

Now. Do the same thing for each term of the right-side expression, reflecting backwards to the left side. If there is a mapping in both directions, you've proved the equivalence.

This is the hard way, though. user287001 is just saying that if you expand out all the terms on both sides, then you'll have your answer already. It's actually easier to just expand the left side out and then expand the right side out and then just compare terms. The way I show you above takes more bookkeeping, so to speak. So I probably wouldn't do it that way. Use the approach user287001 mentioned. You are less likely to make an error that way.

Alternatively, if you need to make a different kind of proof, you can take the above approach to detect (find) the hidden equivalences and then just expand those terms and recombine them back. In this way, you can either manipulate the left-side expression so that it *becomes* the right-side expression, or visa versa. Your call.

Given the above work already done, this is how I'd go:

$$\begin{smallmatrix}
W Y &+& \overline{W} X \overline{Z} &+& \overline{X} Y \overline{Z} &+&  X \overline{Y} Z
\\\\
\left[{W X Y Z}+{W X Y Z}+{W X Y \overline{Z}}+W\overline{X}Y\right] &+& \left[{\overline{W} X Y\overline{Z}}+{\overline{W} X \overline{Y}\overline{Z}}\right] &+& \left[W\overline{X} Y \overline{Z}+{\overline{W}\overline{X} Y \overline{Z}}\right] &+&  \left[{W X \overline{Y} Z}+{\overline{W} X \overline{Y} Z}\right]
\\\\
\left[{W X Y Z}+W\overline{X} Y \overline{Z}+{W X Y \overline{Z}}+W\overline{X}Y\right] &+& \left[{\overline{W} X Y\overline{Z}}+{\overline{W}\overline{X} Y \overline{Z}}\right] &+& \left[{W X Y Z}+{W X \overline{Y} Z}\right] &+&  \left[{\overline{W} X \overline{Y}\overline{Z}}+{\overline{W} X \overline{Y} Z}\right]
\\\\
\left[\left({W X Y Z}+{W X Y \overline{Z}}\right)+\left(W\overline{X}Y+W\overline{X} Y \overline{Z}\right)\right] &+& {\overline{W} Y\overline{Z}} &+& {W X Z} &+&  {\overline{W} X \overline{Y}}
\\\\
\left[W X Y +W\overline{X}Y\right] &+& {\overline{W} Y\overline{Z}} &+& {W X Z} &+&  {\overline{W} X \overline{Y}}
\\\\
W Y &+& {\overline{W} Y\overline{Z}} &+& {W X Z} &+&  {\overline{W} X \overline{Y}}
\end{smallmatrix}$$

Take a careful look at how I expand terms going from the first line to the second line. Then take another very careful look at how I swap terms around when going from the second line to the third line. I've introduced no new terms -- no cheating. Then see how I combine terms back, in moving from the third line to the fourth and fifth lines.

It's a proof. The first line is your right-side expression and the last line is your left-side expression. They are equivalent.

Comment: Expanding both sides into CDNF is indeed "algebraic manipulation", but it is pretty much a direct equivalent of a  proof by truth tables. I wonder if that would be the teacher's intention.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If there was a teacher. As user287001 pointed out, the OP is self-taught.

Comment: Right.. then I guess it would be beneficial to explore how these two are related

Comment: @EugeneSh. I decided to add the proof at the end. Oh, well.

Answer (score 2):

A hint: So, you must prove that boolean expressions A(w,x,y,z) and B(w,x,y,z) are equivalent i.e. both have the same variables w,x,y,z and A=B with every possible combination of w,x,y,z.

The teacher obviously does not accept identical truth tables, but demands algebraic method. Let him get it.

You prove it by making a big expression A xor B or equivalently A'B+AB' and show it becomes identically zero not depending on the values of w,x,y and z.

Looks tiresome, but every term where a variable and its negation are multiplied is zero and that eats off all terms very soon; you will have only 0+0+0....+0

Comment: This method always works. And it's all just boilerplate. I'm curious why Bob hadn't been taught to do that, yet.

Comment: He says he is not a student and will not become one. He claims nothing about what he has been. The limitation to algebraic methods can be an echo or it's invented by Bob who is his own teacher and doesn't yet know everything.

Comment: I was thinking that any book Bob is reading would have covered this. But yeah, good point, still.

Comment: @user287001 I am confused at what you are saying? The left side of the equation is not identical to zero. Are you saying that I should try to write the left side as an expression that uses the XOR operator?

Comment: @Bob Consider the equation `F(x,y,...) = G(x,y,...)`. This is true if and only if `F xor G = 0` for every `x,y, ...`. That is it is enough to prove that `F xor G = 0`  to conclude that `F = G`. This is what this answer is proposing.

Comment: @Bob make the negation of the left side and multiply it with the whole right side. Use distribution, association and DeMorgan's laws to get only a sum of products and see it's zero i.e. every product term has a variabe w...z and it's negation. Do the same with the negation of the right side and the left side.

Comment: @Bob I'll write it out for you. I think I'll leave something for you to do. But I'll take on at least half of it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manipulate the entire expression all at once, I would break it down into sub-problems which can proved independently.

For instance, if you're trying to prove:
$$
  WA + \bar{W}B = WC + \bar{W}D + E
$$
then expand \$E\$ into \$E(W+\bar W)\$ so that every term on the RHS includes either \$W\$ or \$\bar W\$. Collecting terms means you have to prove:
$$
  WA + \bar{W}B = W(C+E) + \bar{W}(D+E)
$$
So now you just have to prove \$A = C+E\$ and \$B = D+E\$.

In your problem, if you split the terms according to \$W\$ and \$\bar W\$ you'll get:

$$
   W(Y+XZ) + \bar W(Y\bar Z + X\bar Y) = W(Y + \bar X Y \bar Z + X \bar Y Z) + \bar W(X\bar Z + \bar X Y \bar Z + X \bar Y Z)
$$
which means your sub-problems are:

1. \$Y+XZ = Y + \bar X Y \bar Z + X \bar Y Z\$
2. \$Y\bar Z + X\bar Y = X\bar Z + \bar X Y \bar Z + X \bar Y Z \$

You could then pick another variable and split each of these sub-problems into two smaller sub-problems. Each sub-problem becomes simpler as it involves one less variable.

Two identities I've found helpful for proving boolean formulas by hand are:

\begin{align}
  A + \bar A B &= A + B \\
  A + AB & = A
\end{align}

As a demonstration, here's a proof of the first sub-problem:

\begin{align}
  Y + XZ 
    &= (Y + Y \bar X \bar Z)+ XZ \\
    &= Y + Y \bar X \bar Z + XZ \\
    &= (Y + XZ) + Y \bar X \bar Z \\
    &= Y + \bar Y X Z + Y \bar X \bar Z \\
\end{align}