# K-Map SOP and POS forms not matching

Tags: digital-logic

I am new to K-maps. I am a bit confused on this. I have this K-Map that gives different min SoP and  min PoS for the same map.

I have attached an image containing the K-Map and my calculations.

I know minSoP and minPoS should be the same, but I am not able to prove algebraically that min SoP of this K-Map = min PoS of this K-Map. I have checked my calculations many times but still I am at a loss. Please help.

The question is that we first have to find SoP and PoS independently and then prove they are same so we cannot use de-Morgan to find PoS from SoP, instead we need to group 0's and find PoS.[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to put variable names on that kmap

Comment: Please draw a proper K map, with labels for the inputs and their values for each row and column. Show us how you circled implicants. If you are trying to use Boolean algebra to demonstrate equivalence, show us all of your work.

Comment: You probably aren't ordering the inputs on the rows and columns properly. It needs to follow gray code (i.e. only one bit changes at a time 00 01 11 10, that way you can actually group them to make sense, NOT 00 01 10 11). Hard to say what you did though when we can't see what you did.

Comment: You need to expand and deduct PoS to SoP, not using Karnaugh as your prof said. The first expansion becomes: (a'c+ a'd+a' + bc+bd+a'b).(a+b+d').(c'+d+b'). If you don't get the same result as SoP, your SoP or PoS, or both were incorrect.

Comment: Oh I thought it's a standard so I didn't include my working. I am attaching an image of the kmap.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson I have attached my workings

Comment: @jay I know this that's why I am confused.

Comment: @Alex Oh, I see. Rotate your picture right, then you will get about 10 answers immediately. :-)

Comment: Umm.. if I try rotating it says image size exceeds 2imb.

Comment: Any help or idea why I am going wrong? No need to give a complete answer.

Comment: @Alex For the zeros, why didn't you circle up four of them in a *square* group?? [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WWab.jpg)?

Comment: @Alex And there are more opportunities, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've circled things up a bit, with red and blue:

[image]

For SOP (red), you have \$bd + \overline{a\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{c\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}d  + \overline{a\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{b\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{c\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}} + \overline{b\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{c\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{d\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\$. But this can be reduced in two ways (easily seen in the above image):

1. \$bd + \overline{a\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{b\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{c\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}} + \overline{b\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{c\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{d\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\$
2. \$bd + \overline{a\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{c\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}d  + \overline{b\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{c\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\overline{d\vphantom{bd + \overline{a}\overline{c}d  + \overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} + \overline{b}\overline{c}\overline{d}}}\$

For POS (blue), you have \$\overline{b\overline{d} + \overline{b}c + a\overline{b}d+c\overline{d}+\overline{b}cd}\$ but the term, \$\overline{b}cd\$, is completely unnecessary. But if you look closely there, you also can see that the term, \$c\overline{d}\$, is also unnecessary. So all you need is:

3. \$\overline{b\overline{d} + \overline{b}c + a\overline{b}d}\$

Is this sufficient help?

Comment: yes yes thanks a lot

Comment: One doubt. if I expand 3. will I get exp-1 or exp-2? I am getting something different :(

Comment: I am getting an extra term of bc'd + a'c'd after simplifying exp-3

Comment: @Alex You should get (b' + d)(b + c')(a' + b + d'), yes?

Comment: Yes i got that, then I simplified further to get sum of products expression, but the final sop differs from exp-1 and exp-2

Comment: @Alex I don't know what's bothering you, though, as you haven't shown me. Perhaps it is that algebraic simplification isn't always obvious. It's usually easier to see using k-maps (if the variables are few enough.) For an example that illustrates some of the subtle issues in algebraic simplication, because of how terms need to be shifted about to show equivalency, have a [look here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/572426/38098). Read through the steps *very closely* there, at the end. I think you'll see why algebraic operations aren't a "slam dunk." You do have to think, at times.

Comment: ahhh got it now, I was actually simplifying blindly

Comment: @Alex Great! I thought it might be something like that. It gets all of us from time to time.