# How to convert SoP to NOR?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

- I have a logical expression: F = AB + AC + CB
- I know its equivalent
  expression via NOR: R = (A ⊽ B) ⊽ (A ⊽ C) ⊽ (C ⊽ B)
- It is assumed that the desired expression in NOR is unknown.
- I know De Morgan's laws, and that the element NOR is equivalent to the expression !P!Q!S, which is equivalent to the expression !(P + Q + S). But I can't get PoS expression through double negation. For example: !( (!A+!B)(!A+!C)(!C+!B) )

How to prove that in order to convert SoP to NOR, it is desirable to convert SoP to PoS first?
How to bring the expression F to R?

Comment: How does one prove *desirable*? (*"How to prove that in order to convert SoP to NOR, it is desirable to convert SoP to PoS first?"*) In any case, It just sounds to me as though you need some sit-down time for playing. You need to expand everything and rearrange. See [this answer I gave](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/572426/38098) to a different question. It's related, though you may not yet see why. You couldn't use double negation because you didn't include *all* the terms and didn't then rearrange stuff from there. If you still need help I'll write something if no one else bothers.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'll +1 the question to see if it gets the attention of my betters. (Despite the fact that I don't like to see *desirable* as the object of *proof* in the same sentence.) One more thing to remember, imagination is vital. And that means NOT mechanical 'follow the rules' codified, straight forward application of all the stuff you are being taught. It means being able to climb out of the well-worn paths you are trained to use. To move beyond them, climb out into unknown and unexplored ways of thinking. Work on that, too. ***Use*** your imagination. Develop it.

Comment: If it's not clear already you need to see that A B = A B C + A B !C, that A C = A B C + A !B C, and that B C = A B C + !A B C. Use those to replace your original equation. Re-arrange the results and move towards the solution you desire. **Imagine**!! This is the time to stretch yourself.

Comment: @jonk F is a simplified form of my original expression: !ABC + A!BC + AB!C + ABC

Comment: Very good. Now use your imagination! The double negation gets you directly ***and unimaginatively*** towards !( (!A + !B) (!A + !C) (!B + !C) ). Which you don't want. Think about how to re-arrange things so you get where you want to be!!! It is there in front of you! Perhaps read the link I gave. It may help. But you can do this! I really do NOT want to steal this process from you. Stuff handed on a silver platter doesn't stick as well.

Comment: @jonk I have found that the expression A⊽B = !A!B is written in CNF, and that CNF is more convenient for proving theorems. Perhaps it's like bringing fractions to the same denominator. Knowing that any expression can be converted to the CNF. And knowing that any expression can be converted to Peirce's arrows. So, any expression can be brought to Peirce's arrows through the CNF. What do you think of my proof of how to convert any expression to Peirce's arrows?

Comment: Remember that if AB= ABC+AB!C  ... then it says that ABC is "included" in AB ... so you don't need ABC when you find an expression as AB+ABC = AB(1+C)= AB ...

Answer (score 0):

As checking of transformation, here is a simulation for some "transformation" of the circuit.

[image]